# How do I get MySQL to return a ranking tied to a subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to make a chart that includes a couple variables charting the sum of ticket sales to a college sporting event by year and where it ranks among the other events present in the database. I'm having trouble figuring out a way to make the rank correspond to each row's individual year.

Here's what I'm starting with:

```
SELECT
Year as year,
School,
`Ticket Sales`,
(SELECT 
    COUNT(School)+1 
    FROM schools 
    WHERE Year = 2016 AND `Ticket Sales` > (
        SELECT `Ticket Sales` 
            FROM schools 
            WHERE School = "College" AND Year = 2016)
        ) as Rank
FROM schools
WHERE School = "College"
ORDER BY Year DESC
```

And here's what I'm getting back (notice it gives 15 - the rank for the first year - for every instance):

```
Year    School  Ticket Sales Rank
2016    College 29054868    15
2015    College 29586555    15
2014    College 26928635    15
2013    College 25888524    15
2012    College 23432735    15
2011    College 26467598    15
2010    College 18395654    15
2009    College 20711850    15
2008    College 17107971    15
2007    College 17287093    15
2006    College 15351891    15
2005    College 12767307    15
```

Edit: To be clear, the number under rank should be different for each year. 2015's rank is different than 2016's and different than 2014's was, etc.

Comment: You are selecting Rank as a subquery which returns 15 for all the records. Inorder to help you, can you please give some sample data and the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you are trying to accomplish :

```
SELECT Year,
       School,
       sum(`Ticket Sales`) as `Ticket Sales`,
       Count(*) as Rank
FROM schools
WHERE School = "College"
GROUP BY Year,
      School
ORDER BY Year DESC
```

See sample result [**here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d6be1/1).